# How to stop a branch merged with develop branch to be merged with master branch?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

During coding I create a *feature* branch from the *develop* branch. When everything is OK I merge this *feature* branch to *develop* branch.

Later for production deployment I merge this *develop* branch to *maste*r branch on production.

Is there a way to prevent a *feature* branch merged in the *develop* branch to be merged with *master* branch. That means when I merge my *develop* branch to *master* branch that particular branch should not be merged with *master* branch?

On my staging server I use *develop* branch and on production I use *master* branch.I had a task/code change that should be on staging only. It should not go to production that is on master branch.

I use bitbucket and source tree for the version control.

Comment: That's not possible, unless you first [*revert*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commit that merged `feature` into `develop`, before merging `develop` into `master`.

Comment: @Muk Unclear for me what you realy want to achieve, could you describe step-by-step your problem, please? Do you want the changes from `feature` branch to get into `master`?

Comment: @zaratustra Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Muk have you tried to use [`cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)?

Comment: @zaratustra If I use cherry pick will it be for one time only? Because I frequently merge develop branch with master branch to deploy the changes.

Comment: I see, you might want to adopt another git branch model, take a look at [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: @zaratustra model suggested by you is good.This can handle situations like I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible indeed. But if you have already merged your feature branch in develop branch and for some reason if you don't want to merge changes to master branch, you can cherry pick changes from develop to master means you can put specific commits to master.